# SQL Group by Minute- Expanded

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on something similar to this post here:
[TS SQL - group by minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758229/ts-sql-group-by-minute)

However mine is pulling from an message queue, and I need to see an accurate count of the amount of traffic the Message Queue is creating/ sending, and at what time

```
Select * From MessageQueue mq
```

My expanded version of this though is the following:
A) User defines a start time and an end time (Easy enough using Declare's @StartTime and @EndTime

B) Give the user the option of choosing the "grouping". Will it be broken out by 1 minutes, 5 minutes, 15 minutes, or 30 minutes (Max).  (I had thought to do this with a CASE statement, but my test problems fall apart on me.)

C) Display the data to accurately show a count of what happened during the interval (Grouping) selected.

This is where I am at so far

SQL Blob:

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime
DECLARE @EndTime datetime

SELECT DATEPART(n, mq.cre_date)/5 as Time  --Trying to just sort by 5 minute intervals
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),mq.Cre_Date,101)
    ,COUNT(*) as results

FROM dbo.MessageQueue mq

WHERE mq.cre_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
GROUP BY DATEPART(n, mq.cre_date)/5 --Trying to just sort by 5 minute intervals
         , eq.Cre_Date
```

This is the output I would like to achieve:

```
[Time]     [Date]           [Message Count]
  1300     06/26/2012               5
  1305     06/26/2012               1
  1310     06/26/2012               100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you want:

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME, @EndTime DATETIME
DECLARE @Interval INT

SET @StartTime = '20130625'
SET @EndTime = '20130627'
SET @Interval = 5


SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),mq.Cre_Date,101) [Date],
        CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,mq.Cre_Date)/@Interval*@Interval,0)) [Time],
        COUNT(*) Results
FROM dbo.MessageQueue mq
WHERE mq.cre_date >= @StartDate 
AND mq.cre_date <= @EndDate 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),mq.Cre_Date,101),
         CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,mq.Cre_Date)/@Interval*@Interval,0))
```

Comment: @KyleHale Oh, the `GETDATE()` there was a bad copy-paste, fixed it now.

Comment: You guys never cease to amaze me. Honestly I can't thank you enough for this. I need a few more Rep before I can "Vote Up", butI have marked this as the answer.